# Moving a path based shape in Raphael is not fluid

Tags: jquery, raphael

I have defined a simple square shape on a black background and try to 'animate' it by using repeating `.transform()` calls. With the code below it just moves from left to right at a constant speed. I notice two things:

- The vertical lines 'flicker' while moving, sometimes it looks like the top part and the bottom part of the line are in different positions (something like in the old day when you tried to draw vertical lines on a CRT monitor while the screen itself was refreshing)
- The animation often stops for a moment before continuing (little 'hickups' in the movement).

*So I have the feeling I'm not doing the right thing. Should I use a different function to move path based objects? Or should I change the way it updates?*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var R = Raphael("display", 640, 480);

    R.rect(0, 0, 640, 480, 10).attr({
        fill : "#000",
        stroke : "#666"
    });

    var path = "M10,20L10,100L100,100L100,20L10,20";

    rectangle= R.path(path).attr({
        "stroke" : "#0f0",
        "stroke-width" : 2
    });

    update();
});

function update() {
    D=D+1;
    var translation_string = "T"+D+",0";
    rectangle.transform(translation_string);
    setTimeout(update, 20);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably best to not manually manage animations with your own event timers. For example, instead of calling update(), do this:

```
rectangle.animate( { "transform": "T410,0" }, 800, "<>", function() {
    rectangle.animate( { "transform": "T0,0" }, 800, "<>");
});
```

You should see a fairly smooth animation that takes the rectangle rightward, then back.

Try it in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YadqP/

Comment: Which shows how careful one should ask his questions. The answer is correct, the animation is smooth. But the intention of this attempt was to create an object that could be moved using the arrow keys. So I cannot use an animation since I will not know how long the total movement will be.

Comment: You could, however, still use this logic. Raphael has a neat .stop() method that will interrupt an animation mid-stride and smoothly phase it to the next one. In other words, rectangle.stop().animate( { new coordinates here } ); will still work for you.